# What does the German abbreviation "ca." mean?

Tags: meaning, abbreviation

What does the German abbreviation *ca.* mean? And what is the corresponding word for it?

I did not find it on [abbreviations.com](http://www.abbreviations.com/acronyms/GERMAN/7).

Comment: Well, it's there on this website. Just hard to find there among hundreds of abbreviations.

Comment: Providing word to word translations (especially for words or abbreviations that are totally common) is not the purpose of this website. You could, however, rephrase your question and ask in what situations it would be  appropriate to use *ca.* as opposed to *circa*, *zirka*, *ungefähr* and *annäherungsweise*.

Comment: Pro tip: use [an actual dictionary](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ca_) ;) (In this case, even an [English dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ca#ca_Residual_000) would have sufficed, but you could not have known that in advance.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is short for "circa" which means "approximately."

Comment: Note the German word is "zirka", even if the Latin original (which is an abbreviation of "circum ea" by itself)  is very commonly used as well.

Comment: @tofro while I have seen the germanized spelling, it seems to be much less common than either the abbreviation or the latinized one (ca. > circa >> zirka in prevalence).

Comment: @Chieron This Ngram shows "zirka" has ben superceded by "circa" ca. 1980 Before that time, "zirka" was leading (and both are vastly outnumbered by the abbreviation "ca."): 

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=circa%2Czirka%2Cca.&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccirca%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcirca%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCirca%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Czirka%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bzirka%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BZirka%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cca.%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @tofro In the Ngram, it's interesting to notice the sudden shift in spelling towards the germanized form around the turn of the century and WWI.